# Security/Security.h file not found [Lexical or Preposessor issue]

Tags: iphone, xcode

[image: Screenshot of my iPhone app]

Screenshot of my iPhone app where I get this error when I am trying to create an archive file, can anyone help me to solve this issue. My Xcode version is 4.6.2

Comment: Did you include the `Security` framework?

Comment: yes it's already there.

Comment: Maybe try `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`.

Comment: Hi msgambel thanks for your answer. But it's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add Security.Framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section in "Project Build Phases"
[image]

Comment: Thanks Hai Hw. You solved my issue for this error but after adding the security framework I got facing another issue ' library not found for - lobjc "

Comment: I think you are misspelling. It may be -ObjC in the "Other Linker Flag"

Comment: This is the exact line "ld: library not found for -lobjc
clang: errot: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" and also I am sending you the screenshot of the error https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55174883/Linker%20Error.png